# I want to use Substring function and append

Tags: arrays, swift

[image][image]

I'm making app that get data from bluetooth device and process it.

App will gat 15 digit with numbers and semi-colon.

And Throw semicolon away and put numbers apart as 5/3/3/3

And use it for getting Sum and Average.

```
for j in 0...splitUserData.endIndex-1 { =
    if splitUserData[j].count == 14{ 
        checkedUser14Data.append(String(splitUserData[j])) 
    }
}

for k in 0...checkedUser14Data.endIndex-1{
    var strForCal = checkedUser14Data[k]
    var valDis = strForCal[strForCal.startIndex...strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)] 
    UserDis.append("valDis")
    var valXAngle = strForCal[strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)...strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)]
    UserXAngle.append(String(valXAngle))
    var valYAngle = strForCal[strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 8)...strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)]
    UserYAngle.append(String(valYAngle))
    var valZAngle = strForCal[strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)...strForCal.index(strForCal.startIndex, offsetBy: 13)]
    UserZAngle.append(String(valZAngle))

}
```

But I have found that in debugging mode, it didn't work well likes valDis hasn't any value.

So I want to know this is right or What is the problem.

************************ added ************************

```
var receivedUserData : String = ""
    var splitUserData : Array<Substring> = []
    var checkedUser14Data : Array<String> = []
    public var UserDis : Array<String> = []
    public var UserXAngle : Array<String> = []
    public var UserYAngle : Array<String> = []
    public var UserZAngle : Array<String> = []
```

for your information, I set variables like this.

************************ added2 ************************

I am debugging this app and there is no UserDis.apped("valDis") process.

Comment: Set breakpoints. What happens inside your loops?

Comment: Please show some examples of `receivedUserData`.

Comment: @OOPer Data is just like what I draw in picture. "10000100200300;", "11000110210310;", "12000120220320;" and so On

Comment: @Gereon I added my debugging screen shot

Comment: I guess `receivedUserData` is a concatenated single String...

Comment: Your code is hard to read and not efficient, but has no problems. The variable `valDis` has the right value (first 5 digits) at each iteration. What do you think is the problem. Please clarify.

Comment: Note that it should be `UserDis.append(valDis)` (without quotes)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I solved this problem with your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Regular Expression.

The pattern captures the 4 values (5, 3, 3, 3 digits)

```
let string = "10000100200300;"

let pattern = "^(\\d{5})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3});$"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)) {
    let firstValue = String(string[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!])
    let secondValue = String(string[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!])
    let thirdValue = String(string[Range(match.range(at: 3), in: string)!])
    let fourthValue = String(string[Range(match.range(at: 4), in: string)!])
    print(firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, fourthValue)
}
```

Or if the source type is `Data` extract the bytes and then create the strings

```
let data = Data([0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3B])

let firstValue = String(data: data[0..<5], encoding: .ascii)
let secondValue = String(data: data[5..<8], encoding: .ascii)
let thirdValue = String(data: data[8..<11], encoding: .ascii)
let fourthValue = String(data: data[11..<14], encoding: .ascii)
```